# SQL column encryption using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am starting to work on a project that requires the encryption of a number of columns in a number of tables.

It works in some databases. But in some databases it gives an error like below.

Everything seems to go well… BUT the Powershell script ends up returning this error...

```
    Set-SqlColumnEncryption ; Unable to reconnect to database: Execution expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
    
+ Set-SqlColumnEncryption -ColumnEncryptionSettings $encryptionChanges  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-SqlColumnEncryption], SqlReverseEngineerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EncryptionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.AlwaysEncrypted.SetColumnEncryption
```

Here is my script :

```
Import-Module SqlServer
# Set up connection and database SMO objects
$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=db;Initial Catalog=$dbName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=0;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Packet Size=4096;Application Name=`"Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`""
$smoDatabase = Get-SqlDatabase -ConnectionString $sqlConnectionString

$encryptionChanges = @()

$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName1.Column1' -EncryptionType Plaintext
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName1.Column2' -EncryptionType Plaintext
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName1.Column3' -EncryptionType Plaintext
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName1.Column4' -EncryptionType Plaintext
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName2.Column1' -EncryptionType Plaintext
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName2.Column2' -EncryptionType Plaintext
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName3.Column1' -EncryptionType Plaintext
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName3.Column2' -EncryptionType Plaintext
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName4.Column1' -EncryptionType Plaintext
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName 'dbo.TableName5.Column2' -EncryptionType Plaintext

Set-SqlColumnEncryption -ColumnEncryptionSettings $encryptionChanges -InputObject $smoDatabase
```

Comment: EncryptionType `Plaintext` doesn't do anything.

Comment: SMO's backend might have a [default statement timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.statementtimeout?view=sql-smo-160#microsoft-sqlserver-management-common-serverconnection-statementtimeout) of 600 sec.

Comment: This may be useful, it walks through setting up column encryption: https://blog.dbre.dev/2022/07/using-encrypted-columns-with.html

Comment: Maybe use `-MaxDowntimeInSeconds` etc?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  Well how can I fix it ?